# Chrome devtools wont pick up script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Code seems to keep breaking when i add new things in. The game is supposed to ask to fight or skip. when fight is chosen, the game fights. If skip is chosen, the game goes to next fight until the end. If cancel is selected, game should say invalid input. Yet it breaks and I can just hit enter without entering anything and the game runs all the way. Not even chrome devtools is detecting the scrip until after everything is ran.

```js
// Game States
// "WIN" - Player robot has defeated all enemy robots
//    * Fight all enemy robots
//    * Defeat each enemy robot
// "LOSE" - Player robot's health is zero or less

var playerName = window.prompt("What is your robot's name?");
var playerHealth = 100;
var playerAttack = 10;
var playerMoney = 10;

var enemyNames = ["Roborto", "Amy Android", "Robo Trumble"];
var enemyHealth = 50;
var enemyAttack = 12;

var fight = function(enemyName) {
    while (playerHealth > 0 && enemyHealth > 0) {
      // ask user if they'd liked to fight or run
      var promptFight = window.prompt('Would you like FIGHT or SKIP this battle? Enter "FIGHT" or "SKIP" to choose.');
  
      // if user picks "skip" confirm and then stop the loop
      if (promptFight === "skip" || promptFight === "SKIP") {
        // confirm user wants to skip
        var confirmSkip = window.confirm("Are you sure you'd like to quit?");
  
        // if yes (true), leave fight
        if (confirmSkip) {
          window.alert(playerName + ' has decided to skip this fight. Goodbye!');
          // subtract money from playerMoney for skipping
          playerMoney = playerMoney - 10;
          console.log("playerMoney", playerMoney)
          break;
        }
      }
  
      // remove enemy's health by subtracting the amount set in the playerAttack variable
      enemyHealth = enemyHealth - playerAttack;
      console.log(
        playerName + ' attacked ' + enemyName + '. ' + enemyName + ' now has ' + enemyHealth + ' health remaining.'
      );
  
      // check enemy's health
      if (enemyHealth <= 0) {
        window.alert(enemyName + ' has died!');
  
        // award player money for winning
        playerMoney = playerMoney + 20;
  
        // leave while() loop since enemy is dead
        break;
      } else {
        window.alert(enemyName + ' still has ' + enemyHealth + ' health left.');
      }
  
      // remove players's health by subtracting the amount set in the enemyAttack variable
      playerHealth = playerHealth - enemyAttack;
      console.log(
        enemyName + ' attacked ' + playerName + '. ' + playerName + ' now has ' + playerHealth + ' health remaining.'
      );
  
      // check player's health
      if (playerHealth <= 0) {
        window.alert(playerName + ' has died!');
        // leave while() loop if player is dead
        break;
      } else {
        window.alert(playerName + ' still has ' + playerHealth + ' health left.');
      }
    }
};

for (var i = 0; i < enemyNames.length; i++) {
  if (playerHealth > 0) {
    window.alert("Welcome to Robot Gladiators! Round " + (i + 1));
    var pickedEnemyName = enemyNames[i];
    enemyHealth = 50;
    // debugger;
    fight(pickedEnemyName);
  }
}

// fight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only testing if SKIP is entered. In all other cases (including no input) you run the fight.

If you want to ensure that either skip or fight is entered, try this:

```
var promptFight = ""
while ( !(promptFight == "SKIP" || promptFight == "FIGHT")) {
    promptFight = window.prompt('Would you like FIGHT or SKIP this battle? Enter "FIGHT" or "SKIP" to choose.').trim().toUpperCase();
}
```

This will re-display the prompt until either skip/fight (regardless of case or spaces added at the start or end).